# Bulk importing JSON into SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, powershell, psobject

I need to bulk import data into a SQL Server database.

My JSON looks like this:

```
$projectsJSON = @"
[
    {
        "id":  35,
        "created_at":  "2016-01-12T11:40:36+01:00",
        "customer_id":  34,
        "name":  ".com",
        "note":  "COMXXXX-",
        "updated_at":  "2016-07-15T12:13:54+02:00",
        "archived":  false,
        "customer_name":  "PMName"
    },
    {
        "id":  23,
        "created_at":  "2010-01-11T12:58:50+01:00",
        "customer_id":  43,
        "name":  "PN",
        "note":  "{\r\n    \"Billable\": 1\r\n}\r\n",
        "updated_at":  "2017-11-24T15:49:31+01:00",
        "archived":  false,
        "customer_name":  "MSM"
    }
]
"@

$projects = $projectsJSON |ConvertFrom-Json
$dt2 = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
$dt2 = $projects|select-object id, created_at, customer_id, name, note, updated_at, archived, customer_name

$bulkCopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($DestConnStr, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepIdentity)
$bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600
$bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "project"
$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt2)
```

Unfortunatelly, I keep getting this error:

> Cannot convert argument "rows", with value: "System.Object[]", for
>   "WriteToServer" to type "System.Data.DataRow[]": "Cannot convert the
>   "@{id=35; created_at=2016-01-12T11:40:36+01:00; customer_id=34;
>   name=.com; note=COMXXXX-; updated_at=2016-07-15T12:13:54+02:00;
>   archived=False; customer_name=PMName}" value of type
>   "Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type
>   "System.Data.DataRow"." At P:\PsideSync\sync.ps1:261 char:3
>   +         $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt2)
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

What would be the right way to import lots of JSON Data into SQL Server?

TIA

Comment: I don't know the `Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` object but there is clearly something wrong with the `$dt2` object; first you define it as a `DataTable` and than you overwrite it with an array of `PSCustomObject`s. There are several sides that discribe how to build a DataTable, take e.g.: http://www.intrntpirate.com/2014/09/26/creating-a-data-table-in-powershell/

Comment: I guess this is the easy solution: https://gist.github.com/gravejester/3052e0e54e35bebc3257 and presume this is the syntax: `$dt2 = $projects | select-object id, created_at, customer_id, name, note, updated_at, archived, customer_name | ConvertTo-DataTable` (btw. note the `note` in your second object is not a `[string]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @IRon notes you are filling $dt2 twice. I assume you want to go with the second initialization.

You could get Out-DataTable from here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd

Then it's just a matter of calling

```
$projects = $projectsJSON |ConvertFrom-Json
$dt2 = $projects|select-object id, created_at, customer_id, name, note, updated_at, archived, customer_name

$bulkCopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($DestConnStr, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepIdentity)
$bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600
$bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "project"
$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt2 | Out-DataTable)
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Thanx. I got Out-DataTable from :
https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell